# Thunderbird: Highlight Mails containing unprocessed invitations

Tags: thunderbird

Is there a way to  highlight mails which contain unprocessed invitations?

I would like to see the highlighted line here:

[image]

If the message contains this:

[image]

Is there a way to get this?

For me it is important to see if the invitation is **unprocessed**. If it is processed, then the preview line should not be highlighted any more.

Comment: I asked here, too: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/thunderbird-highlight-mails-containing-unprocessed-invitations/32994

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird provides a range of tools to manage your email. You will need to see how these tools may aid you in optimizing your workflow with respect to invitations. **Thunderbird tags** combined with **Message filters* can give you 95% what you want.

- Tags actually provide a highlight to the message in your message list. You may thus create a tag for "Invitations".
- Create a *Message filter* that automatically applies the tag to incoming messages that contain "This message contains an invitation to an event". As a result, any incoming invitations will automatically be highlighted.
- Once you processed the invitation, you will manually need to remove the tag. Removing a tag is extremely easy and quick in Thunderbird, requiring one single keystroke, either with the message open or from within the message list. Tags have a number assigned. Each tag can be toggled by pressing the number of the tag. Thus, as soon as you processed the invitation, press that number and the tag will be removed.

As a result,

- invitations will automatically be highlighted in your message list;
- With a single keypress, you remove the highlight when you processed the message;
- With the "Quick filter" you can filter on tags, and this way, display only your invitations at any time.

Comment: Yes, your solution sounds solid. Nevertheless I hope that this will get easier in the future.

Comment: Probably not any email solution provides out of the box what you want. They however provide tools that you can employ yourself as you see fit to maximally streamline your workflow.

Comment: How do you filter such invitations when this text is not in the mail ?